# Keyword list operators in Boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse an object where the order of the attributes should not matter.

For example, parsing employee

> employee { surname = "doe", firstname = "john", age = 30 }

should be the same as

> employee { age = 30, firstname = "john", surname = "doe"}

So ideally my rule should be something like (don't mind the lack of formal definition)

```
unordered_rule %= lit("employee") >> "{" 
             >> kwd("surname")["=" > quoted_string] 
            / kwd("age")["=" > int_] 
            / kwd("firstname")["=" > quoted_string] 
            / kwd("age")["=" > int] >> "}";
```

But firstly, how do I incorporate the separating commas into the parsing rule? And for my C++ struct `struct employee { std::string firstname; ... int age; }`, does the order of the attributes matter or how does boost know which keyword corresponds to which attribute even after the struct has been converted to a fusion vector?

This doesn't really add up for me even after reading the documentation on keyword list operators.

Answer (score 1):

Fusion sequences are ordered only. So the order in which the attributes are synthesized must match the order in which the fields have been adapted to the fusion sequence.

I know no elegant way to incorporate the delimiters (I think someone should extend the keyword list parser directive for that... Feel free :)).

You could use a mix of skipping e.g. `(qi::space | ',')` and `qi::lexeme[]` around the relevant items (see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)).

Or you can use a lookahead-asserted repeating expression like

```
unordered_rule %= lit("employee") >> "{" 
        >> (kwd("surname")  >> (&lit('}') | ',')) [ "=" > quoted_string ]
        / kwd("age")       >> (&lit('}') | ',')) [ "=" > int_ ]
        / kwd("firstname") >> (&lit('}') | ',')) [ "=" > quoted_string ]
        / kwd("age")       >> (&lit('}') | ',')) [ "=" > int ]
        >> "}";
```

(not tested for now).

Comment: So is it still possible to use parse a unordered text like my example into a fusion sequence? Or must I do it some other way?

Comment: Huh. I don't think i mentioned any limitations. I just answered your question and showed a way to get the delimiters parsing.